# Swagger Java common header

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I have a REST API server implemented with `Jersey2.0` and integrated with `Swagger` to automate docs and client side applications.

We have our own authentication header (`X-Auth-Token`) which should be applied to all requests in order to use them (Beside the login request that retrieves the token if credentials are correct).

Right now I need to manually add the the token as `ApiImplicitParam` annotation to each of the requests in order for the generated docs to include it:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(name = AuthFilter.AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY, value = "Authorization token", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")})
```

I don't want to hardcode the UI code to add the header itself, as I believe it violated the API encapsulation provided by `swagger.json`. The server definition should provide all the details necessary for the generated docs.

Is there a way to define a custom default annotation for all requests in `Swagger`? Or alternatively use some kind of `Filter` to achieve it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "requests"? You mentioned you annotate each method that needs the header, therefore I assume you talk about the server endpoints. Given that, I don't entirely understand why you say "[...] I don't want to hardcode the UI code to add the header itself, [...]". Maybe a code example of a server method and a client call would help to showcase the problem.